# how to apply logistic regression to test data after the model has been run on the train data

Tags: python-3.x, logistic-regression

I have been trying to learn machine learning but cant figure out how to apply the algorithms to the test data. In this example i have been working through i have been trying to apply a logistic regression model that was used on training data to a new set of test data. The two data sets come in two different csv files: titanic_train.csv and titanic_test.csv. i can apply the model to the train data but cant apply it to the test data.

I am running the model using Anaconda's Jupiter notebook and python 3.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

#this where i load the data

train = pd.read_csv('titanic_train.csv')
test = pd.read_csv('titanic_test.csv')

#impute age


def impute_age(cols):
    Age = cols[0]
    Pclass = cols[1]

if pd.isnull(Age):
    if Pclass == 1:
        return 37
    elif Pclass == 2:
        return 29
    else:
        return 24
else:
    return Age


def convert_data(dataset):
    temp_data = dataset.copy()
    temp_data['Age'] = temp_data[['Age','Pclass']].apply(impute_age,axis=1)
    sex = pd.get_dummies(temp_data['Sex'],drop_first=True)
    embark = pd.get_dummies(temp_data['Embarked'],drop_first=True)
    temp_data.drop(['Sex','Embarked','Name','Ticket'],axis=1,inplace=True)
    temp_data = pd.concat([temp_data,sex,embark],axis=1)
    temp_data.drop('Cabin',axis=1,inplace=True)
    temp_data.dropna(inplace=True)
    return temp_data

train_dataset = convert_data(train) # titanic_train.csv
test_dataset = convert_data(test) # titanic_test.csv


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = 
train_test_split(train.drop('Survived',axis=1), 
                                            train['Survived'], test_size=0.30, 
                                            random_state=101)

#next is the logistic regression

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logmodel = LogisticRegression()
logmodel.fit(X_train,y_train)


# i then get an error 

#ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'S'
#i changed train.drop to train_dataset.drop and then passed it into the model ie this

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = 
train_test_split(train_dataset.drop('Survived',axis=1), 
                                            train['Survived'], 
test_size=0.30, 
                                            random_state=101)


from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logmodel = LogisticRegression()
logmodel.fit(X_train,y_train)

#output was:
#LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, 
#fit_intercept=True,
#      intercept_scaling=1, max_iter=100, multi_class='warn',
 #     n_jobs=None, penalty='l2', random_state=None, solver='warn',
  #    tol=0.0001, verbose=0, warm_start=False)


#then i tried your code

predictions = logmodel.predict(test.drop('Survived', axis = 1))

#this then gives me the report

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print(classification_report(test['Survived'],predictions))

#and get the error   KeyError: "['Survived'] not found in axis"



#so i tried changing it

predictions = logmodel.predict(test_dataset)
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print(classification_report(test['Survived'],predictions))

#and got a new error:         KeyError: 'Survived'
```

just to clear up any confusion ive printed the columns in the train and test data

```
print (train.columns)
print (test.columns)

#Index(['PassengerId', 'Survived', 'Pclass', 'Name', 'Sex', 'Age', 'SibSp',
   'Parch', 'Ticket', 'Fare', 'Cabin', 'Embarked'],
  dtype='object')
#Index(['PassengerId', 'Pclass', 'Name', 'Sex', 'Age', 'SibSp', 'Parch',
   'Ticket', 'Fare', 'Cabin', 'Embarked'],
  dtype='object')
```

i want to be able to apply the model to the new data found in the other file titanic_test.csv

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create a function of the operations you are performing on the training dataset. Because the same operations have to be applied to the test dataset as well. So you should have something like this:

```
train = pd.read_csv('titanic_train.csv')
test = pd.read_csv('titanic_test.csv')

#impute age


def impute_age(cols):
    Age = cols[0]
    Pclass = cols[1]

    if pd.isnull(Age):
        if Pclass == 1:
            return 37
        elif Pclass == 2:
            return 29
        else:
            return 24
    else:
        return Age


def convert_data(dataset):
    temp_data = dataset.copy()
    temp_data['Age'] = temp_data[['Age','Pclass']].apply(impute_age,axis=1)
    sex = pd.get_dummies(temp_data['Sex'],drop_first=True)
    embark = pd.get_dummies(temp_data['Embarked'],drop_first=True)
    temp_data.drop(['Sex','Embarked','Name','Ticket'],axis=1,inplace=True)
    temp_data = pd.concat([temp_data,sex,embark],axis=1)
    temp_data.drop('Cabin',axis=1,inplace=True)
    temp_data.dropna(inplace=True)
    return temp_data

train_dataset = convert_data(train) # titanic_train.csv
test_dataset = convert_data(test) # titanic_test.csv


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train.drop('Survived',axis=1), 
                                                train['Survived'], 
test_size=0.30, 
                                                random_state=101)

#next is the logistic regression

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logmodel = LogisticRegression()
logmodel.fit(X_train,y_train)

predictions = logmodel.predict(test.drop('Survived', axis = 1))

#this then gives me the report

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print(classification_report(test['Survived'],predictions))
```

Comment: I edited the code up above to include your suggestion however im still not getting the desired result. Its says now im getting a value error but i dont know why. My apologies if i am responding incorrectly to your comment as i am still unsure how to format Q&A properly here.

Comment: As i said earlier, whatever you do with train set, you have to do that same with test set. There are few thing which you did with train set, but now with test set.
`1. train['Age'] = train[['Age','Pclass']].apply(impute_age,axis=1)`

`2 . train.drop('Cabin',axis=1,inplace=True)`

`3. train.dropna(inplace=True)(although this will not drop any columns)`

Also, why you are dropping `train.drop(['Sex','Embarked','Name','Ticket'],axis=1,inplace=True)` twice?

Comment: 1. i tried adding the age column though should it not be test['Age'] = test[['Age','Pclass']].apply(impute_age,axis=1) instead of train['Age'] = train[['Age','Pclass']].apply(impute_age,axis=1) as its to do with the test data the same for 2. train.drop('Cabin',axis=1,inplace=True) and 3  train.dropna(inplace=True)(although this will not drop any columns) as they are both do do with test data and not training data at least that was my understanding and thats why the train.drop(['Sex','Embarked','Name','Ticket'],axis=1,inplace=True) was done twice the first for train second for test data

Comment: I have edited the code. try it and let me know if you have any error.

Comment: i have updated the code above and commented the new errors. I am very sorry about this and am grateful for your help if you dont want to continue with this problem i understand

Comment: Okay. So you can only get predictions made by model on the test dataset since columns 'Survived' is not present in the test dataset. Just remove the last line that prints classification_report.

Comment: okay that gets rid of the error but still doesn't predict whether or not someone survives i.e. the test data hasnt got a prediction. the train data gives a result of about 80% accuracy but how do you make the test data predict the survived column

Comment: The values in the `predictions` variable is the prediction that whether a passenger survives or not. Print it and see the output.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked! May i ask one final question, how do you write it into a new column from the variable predictions and then write/save that whole test_dataset to a new csv file. I imagine the variable to a new column is similar to the age column that was made but i got that from an example and am unsure as to the logic behind it

Comment: `test['prediction'] = predictions`


`test.to_csv(index=False)`